# Swift: Is there an OS call in macOS/iOS similar to NSSpellCheck but for getting a word definition from the dictionary,

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I can spell check words like this:

```
import Cocoa

let words = ["happy","flingey","bookinto"]

let spellCheck = NSSpellChecker()

for word in words {
    if spellCheck.checkSpelling(of: word, startingAt: 0).length == 0 {
        print("Word: \(word) is good")
    } else {
        print("Word: \(word) is bad")
    }
}
```

However, the output is:

```
Word: happy is good
Word: flingey is bad
Word: bookinto is good
```

There are some (only some) combinations of valid words, like "book into" but with a missing space which the spellchecker still accepts as valid.

I suspect I might be able to tweak how NSSpellChecker operates to eliminate the issue, however, if I can get the next part working, I won't need to worry about this one.

For a later part of the App (a quiz) I want to let the user see a definition of the word within the App. Something like this

```
import Cocoa

let definer = NSDictionaryDefinition()
let word = "Happy"

if let meaning = definer.getDefinition(for: word) {
   print("\(word): \(meaning.getText())")
}
```

Which would then give:

```
Happy: feeling or showing pleasure or contentment
```

`NSDictionaryDefinition` is just something I made up as the kind of API name I was expecting to find, and obviously given how macOS APIs work it won't be as easy as that, it will probably be within a collection within a container within a callback, or whatever, but I'm happy dealing with all that when I get there, my problem is I can't find any system API that remotely resembles something like `NSDictionaryDefinition`.

My web search is hampered by the fact that Dictionary is also a Swift Collection Type, so I get hundreds of false hits, but even trawling through many of those, I didn't get lucky.

So next I started looking in the API references on the Apple developer site, which is just as painful because it's so vast and sprawling with little by way of a route map through it, but even then I couldn't locate anything.

Does anyone know if this system API exist for Swift (or even Objective-C). I've always assumed it did because the dictionary comes as standard in macOS and most things in macOS are programable via an API. It needs to be a system native API to work offline and also localise to the user automatically.

Please don't suggest third party resources, as I notice a previous question about that got marked as off-topic here. I'm assuming this question is on topic but I genuinely struggle to gauge it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this exists on iOS. Look into `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`. It doesn't give you back the definitions as strings, but you can check if there is a definition for a word and you can show the system-provided dictionary view.